# WebDAV serverside authentication with OWIN OAuth 2

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

As we have a ASP.NET website based mainly on AngularJS client side and WebAPI 2 REST services on the server side, we use OAuth 2 to authenticate our users.ü
This works like a charm.

Now we are thinking of integrating WebDAV into our platform, and were wondering if the Ajax browser as well as the .NET Client and the server component of IT Hit WebDav System can be modified such that they use OAuth bearer tokens to secure their communication.

Is that possible?

Also if so, would it still be possible to open such a document using MS Word and edit it right away?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I meanwhile found out, that this is perfectly possible - as far as the framework and the server are concerned.
The real problem is, however, that only ms office clients support this by using"forms based authentication".

However I never tried it out. We cancelled that feature beforehand.